# Overriding loadTiles in Mapkit Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

I am trying to use custom tiles in MapKit with SwiftUI. I have found examples of how to do this if I have URLs for the tile, but I would like the tile to be dynamically and locally generated by the app. To do so, Apple's documentation seems to suggest I would need to override the `loadTile` function in `MKTileOverlay`. Per the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mktileoverlay/1452445-loadtile I have started defining my class as follows:

```
class TileOverlay: MKTileOverlay{
    override func loadTile(at path: MKTileOverlayPath, result: @escaping (Data?, Error?) -> Void){
        //Now what?
    }
}
```

If I understand correctly this function would eventually return a tile, which is a 256x256 image. But how do I actually return this image? It appears that I have to return a closure that returns the image as a `Data?` object, but I was unsuccessful in finding how to convert a 256x256 image to such an object, nor was I able to determine how such a closure should work.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The `data` parameter is the raw data of the image, its "hex"/binary. Then, is will use `UIImage(data: thatData)` to render it (be it a jpg data, png data, etc.)... So, you do: `//find data...; then result(thatImageData, nil)` or `//find data...; then result(nil, anError)` if there was an error. You can use `Data(contentsOf: theTileURL)` (but it's synchrone), so better use `URLSession.dataTask(with: theTileURL) { result($0, $2}}.resume()`, or something like that

Comment: @Larme - Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for! If you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need to do:

- Retrieve raw image data related to the `path`
- Call at some point `result(theRawImageData, nil)` or `result(nil, theErrorYouGot)`

Then the caller of that method will get the closure parameters, and if there is no `error`, try do to: `let image = UIImage(data: theRawImageData)`, and render it where it's needed.

If you already have an image in RAM, you can call `jpegData(compressionQuality:)`, `pngData()` to get `Data`. But as you can see, you'll go from `UIImage` -> `Data` -> `UIImage`, there is a little extra work in the way. So try to keep `Data` instead of `UIImage` if you do some RAM caching (with `NSCache` for instance).

But, if you have a local image on disk (or on a distant URL), you can use `Data(contentsOf:)`. Yet, it's not recommended to use that method, because it's synchrone (ie, blocks the current threads). Prefer using `URLSession` to do that.

```
override func loadTile(at path: MKTileOverlayPath, result: @escaping (Data?, Error?) -> Void){

    //If you use caching:
    if let imageDataInCache = ... {
        result(imageDataInCache, nil)
    } else {
        //Create an `URL` or a `URLRequest` from the `path`:
        let urlOrURLRequest = ...
        //Let's "fetch" the image:
        let task = URLSession.dataTask(with: urlOrURLRequest) { data, response, error in
            //Do additional work if needed, like checking `response`, etc.
            result(data, error)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```